# Check if any item in Python list is None (but include zero)

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a simple test that returns `True` if any of the results of a list are `None`.  However, I want `0` and `''` to not cause a return of `True`.

```
list_1 = [0, 1, None, 4]
list_2 = [0, 1, 3, 4]

any(list_1) is None
>>>False
any(list_2) is None
>>>False
```

As you can see, the `any()` function as it is isn't being helpful in this context.

Comment: Note that the current code means *"if the result of my call to `any` happens to be `None`"* (which, given that it will return `True` or `False` or `raise` an exception, will **never happen**).

Answer (score 184, accepted):

For `list` objects can simply use a membership test:

```
None in list_1
```

Like `any()`, the membership test on a `list` will scan all elements but short-circuit by returning as soon as a match is found.

`any()` returns `True` or `False`, never `None`, so your `any(list_1) is None` test is certainly not going anywhere. You'd have to pass in a generator expression for `any()` to iterate over, instead:

```
any(elem is None for elem in list_1)
```

Comment: And I'd quote that any `Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.` So that was indeed not the right thing to use

Comment: @d6bels Not exactly. It's a perfectly natural use case of `any()`, you just need to combine it with a generator expression. `in` is fine in this case where `list_1` is actually a `List` - in some cases it might be an arbitrary iterable without `__contains__()` implemented, and in such cases the `any()` solution would be the best option.

Comment: @Lattyware: I think d6bels meant the `is None` test.

Comment: This will create troubles when the list contains Numpy arrays. Tom Cornebize has a better solution.

Comment: @frankliuao: I cover two methods in my answer, including the one Tom mentions.

Comment: @frankliuao: but on numpy arrays you probably want to work with [`numpy.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) in any case, and not store `None` objects in a numeric array.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK I probably went through your answer too quickly. The reason why I'm looking for a comparison with numpy array is that I use a function to analyze some data. If it's valid I'll plot it or the function returns a None and I'lll skip it. In this case, I'll need to use None in [checked_data1, checked_data2, ...], so when checked_data* is an array it complains. Using the any() helps.

Comment: Note that this does *not* work if one of the list elements is a `numpy` array. In that case, first use `list()` on the array.

Comment: to check if None doesn't exist, i used `not None in list_1` but it gives this warning: `PEP 8: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'`

Answer (score 26):

```
list_1 = [0, 1, None, 4]

list_2 = [0, 1, 3, 4]

any(x is None for x in list_1)
>>>True

any(x is None for x in list_2)
>>>False
```