# How to write row only if value is not null?

Tags: python

I am converting my json data that I made an api request to to CSV, however some keys in the object have null values.
How can I only write rows that have non null values?

```
count = 0

for stats in nba_team_stats:
    if count == 0:
        header = stats.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csv_writer.writerow(stats.values())
data_file.close()
```

Comment: Beside the point, but why is `csv_writer.writerow(header)` inside the loop? It'd be way easier to move it outside the loop. Then you wouldn't need `count` at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if any item in Python list is None (but include zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836378/check-if-any-item-in-python-list-is-none-but-include-zero). I know it says "list", but a `dict_values` object works the same way.

Comment: where should i put csv_writer.writerow(header) ?

Comment: Before the loop. You just need to check if the list has elements first: `if nba_team_stats: header = nba_team_stats[0].keys(); csv_writer.writerow(header)`

Comment: Oh actually, is `csv_writer` a `DictWriter`? Then you can just do `.writeheader()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the python `csv.DictWriter`, the following example works fine. You don't need a loop to do this.

```
from csv import DictWriter

#Ignore this. This was a test without a file
import io
f = io.StringIO()
f.nam = "t.csv"

nba_team_stats = [{"a": None, "b": 10}, {"b": None, "a": 10}]
csv_writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(nba_team_stats[0].keys()))
csv_writer.writeheader()
csv_writer.writerows(nba_team_stats)

print(f.getvalue())
```

## Output

```
a,b
,10
10,
```

Comment: If the value is not `None` but if its a 'null' as string, then you will have to parse and replace it in the dict with None. If you are using a JSON parser, then this will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Raw python:

```py
import csv
from itertools import chain

it = iter(nba_team_stats)
first_row = next(it, None)
if first_row:
    rows = chain((first_row,), it)

    with open("results.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        # writing keys
        writer.writerow(first_row)
        # writing content, but:
        # ASSUMING EVERY DICT WAS CREATED WITH THE SAME INSERTION ORDER AND PYTHON
        # VERSION IS 3.6 OR HIGHER
        writer.writerows(
            values for values in (row.values() for row in rows) if any(values)
        )
```

The following [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) based solution is an alternative one:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

table = Table.from_rows(nba_team_stats, header=True)
columns = table.columns
table.filter(
    c.or_(*(c.col(column) for column in columns), default=False)
).into_csv("results.csv")
```